# What is going on?

Tags: powershell, windows-11

So I was on powershell in a specific folder, so later on I deleted the folder in windows explorer, and forgot the powershell is still in that deleted folder, so I git cloned while still in that location and it worked! though it opened another powershell and cloned, once done it closed out. So what is going on here? where did it exactly clone to? It doesn't appear in the windows explorer.

I want to know what is going on here

Comment: I think the question (in a reformatted version) is more appropriate on superuser.com - I don't see the programming-related-theme requirement being fulfilled for SO...

Comment: Check the root path of that folder. For example if the deleted folder was somewhere in `drive C` now the cloned repository is in `C:\your_repo_name` or if it was in `drive D`, now it might be in `d:\your_repo_name`.